# Linux [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, python

I have a python script that works on Windows but am having a hard time running it on Ubuntu.

***test.py***

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""
https://pymodbustcp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/server_allow.html

An example of Modbus/TCP server which allow modbus read and/or write only from
specific IPs.

Run this as root to listen on TCP privileged ports (<= 1024).
"""

import argparse
from pyModbusTCP.server import ModbusServer, DataHandler
from pyModbusTCP.constants import EXP_ILLEGAL_FUNCTION


# some const
ALLOW_R_L = ['127.0.0.1', '192.168.0.104']
ALLOW_W_L = ['127.0.0.1']


# a custom data handler with IPs filter
class MyDataHandler(DataHandler):
    def read_coils(self, address, count, srv_info):
        if srv_info.client.address in ALLOW_R_L:
            return super().read_coils(address, count, srv_info)
        else:
            return DataHandler.Return(exp_code=EXP_ILLEGAL_FUNCTION)

    def read_d_inputs(self, address, count, srv_info):
        if srv_info.client.address in ALLOW_R_L:
            return super().read_d_inputs(address, count, srv_info)
        else:
            return DataHandler.Return(exp_code=EXP_ILLEGAL_FUNCTION)

    def read_h_regs(self, address, count, srv_info):
        if srv_info.client.address in ALLOW_R_L:
            return super().read_h_regs(address, count, srv_info)
        else:
            return DataHandler.Return(exp_code=EXP_ILLEGAL_FUNCTION)

    def read_i_regs(self, address, count, srv_info):
        if srv_info.client.address in ALLOW_R_L:
            return super().read_i_regs(address, count, srv_info)
        else:
            return DataHandler.Return(exp_code=EXP_ILLEGAL_FUNCTION)

    def write_coils(self, address, bits_l, srv_info):
        if srv_info.client.address in ALLOW_W_L:
            return super().write_coils(address, bits_l, srv_info)
        else:
            return DataHandler.Return(exp_code=EXP_ILLEGAL_FUNCTION)

    def write_h_regs(self, address, words_l, srv_info):
        if srv_info.client.address in ALLOW_W_L:
            return super().write_h_regs(address, words_l, srv_info)
        else:
            return DataHandler.Return(exp_code=EXP_ILLEGAL_FUNCTION)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # parse args
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-H', '--host', type=str, default='localhost', help='Host (default: localhost)')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', type=int, default=502, help='TCP port (default: 502)')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    # init modbus server and start it
    server = ModbusServer(host=args.host, port=args.port, data_hdl=MyDataHandler())
    server.start()
```

When I run this from SSH I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ben/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyModbusTCP/server.py", line 989, in start
    self._service.server_bind()
  File "/home/ben/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 69, in <module>
    server.start()
  File "/home/ben/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyModbusTCP/server.py", line 992, in start
    raise ModbusServer.NetworkError(e)
pyModbusTCP.server.NetworkError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

If I do a `ls -la` on the directory:

```
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 ben ben 4096 Aug  7 10:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 ben ben 4096 Aug  7 10:50 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ben ben 2522 Aug  7 10:54 test.py
```

Is this a permissions issue?

Comment: Have you read the comment at the top of the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already answered by your script:

> `Run this as root to listen on TCP privileged ports (<= 1024).`

On most Unix-like systems, receiving connections on ports 1–1024 requires privileges – either being root (UID 0) in general, or having the `cap_net_bind_service` privilege (Linux-specific), or such.

You *could* use `sudo` to start the program, but for testing it's safer to just switch it to a different port number (e.g. 1502 or 50502).

(Often TCP servers first start as root, then create the sockets, then switch to an unprivileged user. It doesn't look like ModbusServer allows this to be done easily – it probably expects you to run the entire thing as root.)